# spring mvc hibernate lock row of table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Is there any way to lock user edit row when other user editing this row. I used spring mvc, hibernate and mysql database.
Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html
https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Core_Reference_Guide/transactions-locking.html

Read these links which illustrate how to lock in hibernate.

I would recommend a pessimistic one (select for update based)

quote:
"If Session.load() is called with UPGRADE or UPGRADE_NOWAIT, and the requested object was not yet loaded by the session, the object is loaded using SELECT ... FOR UPDATE. If load() is called for an object that is already loaded with a less restrictive lock than the one requested, Hibernate calls lock() for that object."